# jQuery (window).load() did not acces second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, dom

I'm working on WordPress theme that has a preloading screen, this screen gets hide after entire page complete loading, and my code works perfectly for the past few months, but now the preloading screen did not get hide because the code did not access into `(window).load()` or `window.onload = function ()`.

```
(function ($) {
    console.log("Start");
    window.onload = function () {
       console.log("Done");
    };
})(jQuery);
```

The result is "Start" even when the page has been fully downloaded and the browser shows me entire page.

Info : I'm using WordPress 4.5 multi-website.

Thanks

Comment: Your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/7r48t3jo/. Check the console to see if you have any errors elsewhere that are causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right , The problem not in my code I change "Rocket Loader™" off in CloudFlare and it works back as expected.

Comment: glad you got it fixed. I would just delete the question in that case as it's unlikely to help any one in future as the problem was completely unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `function` which Immediately executes termed as `IIFE` and have a `window.onload` handler in it.

There is **no way** `window.onload` handler will not invoke if it is inside `IIFE`
. `IIFE` will execute immediately as its name suggests and `window.onload` will be called when all the resources inside a webpage are loaded!

Comment: Your double negatives are confusing in the second sentence. Are you saying that his `onload` handler won't work in an IIFE? Because that's incorrect - as you can see from my fiddle in the question comments.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan There is no way window.onload handler will not work inside IIFE.. Quiet convincing i feel... You may edit it to add some value to it...

Comment: So... you're saying his code should work. Which it does.